# Why is my nohup invalid in putty?

Tags: linux, putty, nohup

In my putty terminal, i typed the command as follows:

```
[username@vm186 bin]$ nohup ./mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb-data/ &
[1] 5967
[username@vm186 bin]$ nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
```

then, `ps` showed the `nohup` is apparently invalid !!

```
[username@vm186 bin]$ ps -auxw | grep mongo
username   5967  0.0  0.0  76172  4716 pts/8    Sl   10:03   0:00 ./mongod --dbpath /home/username/mongodb-data/
username   6140  0.0  0.0  61192   780 pts/8    S+   10:04   0:00 grep mongo
```

So, when i close the window, mongod will receive the signal and quit.
What's wrong with my command? or something wrong with my putty configuration?

Comment: Is that ps result from before or after closing the putty window?

Comment: So does you mongo exit after you close putty? Did you do a ps after closing it? if so, what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

On my system (FreeBSD) nohup won't show with ps, but the program it starts will show, and will survive closing putty. Did your program exit after closing putty?

Answer (score 0):

Nohup is not supposed to continue running. It just redirects standard output and standard error, ignores SIGHUP, and executes the program you requested. The requested process totally replaces nohup but inherits the file descriptors and SIGHUP ignoring. That's what prevents the process from terminating when you log out. For more information, look at the source. You're probably using [nohup from coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/nohup.c).